# Can I break a single speed chain with kmc universal link

Tags: chain

It maybe necessary for me to remove the chain for a deep clean. I dont think it's ever been cleared by it's previous owner.

So just to be sure I can use one of these to rejoin the chain:
http://www.wiggle.co.uk/kmc-universal-chain-joining-link/

wanted to make sure just in case I screw up a perfectly working chain.

It is a kmc chain I believe.

Comment: If your chain has a quick or universal link there are tools to open and close them. Note that some links are not meant to be re-used after they have been opened and that normally you don't need a tool to close the link. It's done with a strong push on the pedal.

Comment: I added a master link to my KMC chain and it's working great.  Mine's a KMC Z-series (probably z51, maybe z7, z72 or z8), 116 links, non-bushing.  For the replacement link I wanted KMC Missing Link II Reusable, but the bike store had SRAM PowerLink Silver 8 Speed so that's what I used and it's been great for a year.  So you may have options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the width of the chain. Single speed chains come in 1/8" and 3/32" widths, so you need to know whats on the bike to use an appropriate master link.

You should also check the chain, chainring and cog for wear. If the chain is old and poorly maintained it may be time for a new one (and possibly replacement of other drivetrain parts).

Comment: is the chain width measured inbetween the two plates or outside edge to outside edge.

Comment: Measure between the inner plates (width of the rollers)

Answer (score -1):

I have a single-speed with a KMC chain and that master link. I have removed it and reinstalled it without incident.

Comment: This answer misses one of the critical parts of choosing the right master link: if you use the link on the wrong chain width it won't work properly.